# Message box for wrong value

Tags: vb.net

Im doing a project on vb.net where I have to determine the number of days in a month and wether the given year is leap or not. All the coding is complete for that. All I cannot do is the coding for a message box that will appear if the month is thped incorrectly.

```
Dim year, days As Double
Dim leap As Boolean
Dim monthint As Integer
Dim monthstr As String

days = 0
leap = False

year = txtTheyear.Text
monthstr = txtThemonth.Text

If monthstr = "January" Then
    monthint = 1
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If


If monthstr = "February" Then
    monthint = 2
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If


If monthstr = "March" Then
    monthint = 3
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "April" Then
    monthint = 4
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "May" Then
    monthint = 5
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "June" Then
    monthint = 6
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "July" Then
    monthint = 7
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "August" Then
    monthint = 8
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "September" Then
    monthint = 9
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "October" Then
    monthint = 10
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "November" Then
    monthint = 11
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)
End If



If monthstr = "December" Then
    monthint = 12
    leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
    days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)

    Lstbx1.Items.Add(year)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(leap)
    Lstbx1.Items.Add(days)

End If





With Lstbx1.Items
    .Clear()
    .Add("Year" & vbTab & vbTab & "Is it a leap year" & vbTab & "Month" & vbTab & "Number of days")
    .Add("----" & vbTab & vbTab & "-----------------" & vbTab & "-----" & vbTab & "--------------")
    .Add(txtTheyear.Text & vbTab & vbTab & leap & vbTab & vbTab & txtThemonth.Text & vbTab & days)
End With
```

Coding that ive tried for a message box:

```
If monthstr= "January" or "February" ...
Then ...
Else MsgBox ("Type the month correctly")
End if
```

Comment: You might be looking for `MsgBox.Show("Type the month correctly")`

Comment: @Sharon : I have added an answer that will help you to do these things in a simplified way

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be

```
If monthstr="January" or monthstr="February" ...
```

if you wanne use `IF` here, for `select` see the previos answer by un-lucky

By the way you can code this also in a much shorter way (if you want to)
by simply using something like this:

```
Private Sub btCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btStartButton.Click
    'replace constants with values from your textboxes
    Dim yearPart As String = "2010"
    Dim monthpart As String = "January"

    Dim dt As DateTime
    Try
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01 " + monthpart + " " + yearPart,
                                      "dd MMMM yyyy",
                                      Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        'MsgBox(dt.Year & " " & dt.Month & " " & Date.IsLeapYear(dt.Year))
        Lstbx1.Items.Add(dt.Year)
        Lstbx1.Items.Add(Date.IsLeapYear(dt.Year)))
        Lstbx1.Items.Add(dt.Month)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Incorrect Entry..! Type the month correctly")
    End Try

End Sub
```

The "magic" happens with the second argument of DateTime.ParseExact in the MMMM phrase, because this a format that means the literal representation of your month

Answer (score 0):

The simplified code for the whole scenario:

```
    Dim isSuccess As Boolean = True '<-- variable for checking whether the process completed successfully
    Lstbx1.Items().Clear()
    Select Case monthstr
        Case "January", "jan", "january"
            monthint = 1
        Case "February", "feb", "february"
            monthint = 2
        Case "March", "mar", "march"
            monthint = 3
            'Write cases for other months too
        Case "December", "dec", "december"
            monthint = 12
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Entry..! Type the month correctly")
    End Select
    'No wdo the operation here;
    If Not isSuccess Then
        leap = Date.IsLeapYear(year)
        days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, monthint)
    End If
    ' Here you can populate the List
```

Advantages of using like this:

- Can avoid checking multiple conditions by using select
- The user can enter any of the three( "January", "jan", "january") for `January` Previously it will accept only `January` case sensitive).
- As you requested in the question; You can display a customized message in the `case else` will execute if all other conditions ware false

Comment: Hi thanks so much for this!! It works when i type the month correctly and  when i dont the message box does appear, but if i click okay the program takes me back to the coding and says theres an error with  days= System.DateTime.DaysInMonth  (year, monthint)

Comment: It says month must be between one and twelve. Parameter name: month

Comment: @SharonMeyer: I have updated the answer with solution for that error, please take a look